# 'numpy.float64' object is not callable, How Can i fit it? function to timeseries

Tags: python, function, time-series

```
def mape ( actual , pred ):
    actual, pred = np.array (actual), np.array (pred)
    return np.mean (np.abs ((actual - pred) / actual)) * 100

def mse (actual, pred):
    actual, pred = np.array (actual), np.array (pred)
    return np.square (np.subtract (actual, pred)). mean ()
```

hello everyone :), I have these functions to calculate the MAPE, MSE and SMAPPE.
When I enter the 'test_y' and the 'prediction' in the function I get this error: numpy.float64' object is not callable, how can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zlo9.png)

Comment: What is `np.suma`? What is `fa`? Could you please provide a complete code example that we can run in order to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Sorry, that fuction was wrong, i have just edit it, newby user

Comment: you probably named a variable as mape, this is all we can say without a complete code example.